# Parse Error: Syntax Error,whitespace error

Tags: php

I get a error like

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

for the below code..

```
$string="<b style=margin-left:30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold>"."< a href='tracklocation.php?deviceid=<?=$row['device_id']?>&vno=<?=$row['vehicle_no']?>'>". $row['vehicle_no']."</br>  ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it

```
$string="<b style=margin-left:30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold>"."<a href='tracklocation.php?deviceid={$row['device_id']}&vno={$row['vehicle_no']}'>". $row['vehicle_no']."</a></br>";
```

please notice that instead of using `<?= $variable ?>` if used `{$variable}` to escape parsing the varibale as a string, if you insisted on using `<?= $variable ?>` then you should use `<?= echo $variable; ?>`

Comment: Can you explain what you have changed? It makes your answer understandable.